# I need help identifying a component

Tags: components, identification

I'm hoping you can help me identify this component.
I need to replace it but I don't know its name to find it and purchase it.
[image]

Is difficult to find it in my city.

Comment: Can you upload a higher quality picture?

Comment: Why not just take it with you to your "local electronic market"?

Comment: is very complicated here. I can not to find it. So I think with the name I can check it by internet or another markets.

Comment: *Phoenix Contact* may be the manufacturer, judging from the logo.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist ... especially considering crazy prices on new devices of such primitive construction

Comment: If broken , the parts inside are replaceable.  ( diode , R , LED ) Why do you need another? https://www.mouser.ca/ProductDetail/Phoenix-Contact/2833657?qs=wDrcJJ8tHZX7ewNN1bl8pA==  , common parts worth $0.25 vs $10 for this plug.

Comment: What was the mystery object part of?

Comment: This questions should really include the context of the circuit or equipment surrounding the mystery object.

Answer (score 5):

It's this plug-in LED module from Phoenix Contact:

https://www.phoenixcontact.com/online/portal/us?uri=pxc-oc-itemdetail:pid=2833657&library=usen&tab=1

> Plug-in module, with freewheeling diode and yellow LED, polarity: A1+,
>   A2-, input voltage: 12 ... 24 V DC ±20 %

Answer (score 2):

LED Module for use with PR1 Series, PR2 Series, 24V dc

https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/relay-interfaces/5080203/